# Mocking external api client class for pytest

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I want to mock client Class to external api:

```
class ExternalApiClient:

def __init__(self, request: HttpRequest):
    session = getattr(request, "session", None)

    self.cars = ExternalApiCarsClient(request)
```

This is new feature in my application any my pytests need it to works again, beacuse views use this ExternalApiClient to every operatation f.e.:

```
class CarView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       ...some_code...
            

       client = ExternalApiClient(request)
       client.cars.some_method()

       return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I read unittest.mock documentation and  tried to do like this:

```
@patch('path.to.file.ExternalApiClient', NewMockedClass)
def test_car_update(self):
    ...some_code...
    self.client.patch(car_detail_url) # this patch using update method from CarView
```

but it's not working. My CarView still uses ExternalApiClient instead NewMockedClass. Can I somehow mock whole ExternalApiClient or at least mock separately init method and other methods of this class?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out.

```
@patch('path.to.ExternalApiClient')
def test_car_update(self, mock_client_class):

  mock_client = Mock()
  mock_client_class.return_value = mock_client

  with patch('path.to.view.client', mock_client):

     # make requests to view

     assert mock_client.cars.some_method.called
```

you can mock either the class, init method, or mock the instance directly depending on your needs. In the above example, I am directly mocking the instance.

when mocking a function/method/class, generally need to specify a return value.